# Failed recognize java method during Compute task on remote node

Tags: java, ignite

During compute task execution on remote node getting below java method **error**:

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.aline.cloudedh.base.common.StringUtils.hasEmptyElements(Ljava/util/List;)Z**

NOTE:- deploymentMode set as "**PRIVATE**", running on Thick client

Your help will be greatly appericated

Comment: Do you have this class on remote node? Does it have that method? Do you expect it to be peer loaded?

Comment: i'm doing dynamic class deployment. Yes i have this method and  It's recognizing and working fine on local machine/node but failed to recognize on while executing on remote node.

Comment: Is it possible that a different copy of this class is already present on remote node? Do you have a reproducer project to share?

Comment: Wrong classloader?

Comment: @alamar, No copy exists on that node, Facing same issue even on fresh brand new node. But one intersting thing is, i know it's sounds weird but we have 3 remote nodes, working fine in one of the node, on rest two nodes job failing. All are started with same configuration (docker containers).

Comment: @alamar is it anything i missed or need to set any property for remote node, please help?

Comment: There must be some difference between nodes after all.